# How to check if the checkbox is selected or not

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I made a custom listview, following is the code:

```
ListView<Sector> sectorList = new ListView();
sectorList.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 21px;");
sectorList.setItems(data2);
sectorList.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Sector>, ListCell<Sector>>() {
    @Override
    public ListCell<Sector> call(ListView<Sector> param) {
        return new XCell();
    }
});
```

.

```
class XCell extends ListCell<Sector>{
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Sector sector, boolean empty){
        super.updateItem(sector, empty);
        if(!empty){
            CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(sector.getName());
            checkbox.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold;");
            checkbox.setSelected(true);

            Label label = new Label("          "+sector.getDescription());
            label.setStyle("-fx-font-style: italic;");

            VBox root = new VBox(5);
            root.setPadding(new Insets(8));
            root.getChildren().addAll(checkbox,label);

            setGraphic(root);
        }else{
            setGraphic(null);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Is there a way to loop through the listview's items and check if the checkbox is selected or not? How?

Comment: What is the purpose of those checkboxes. If they used only for multiple selection, you can bind their valueproperty to cell items selected prperty, and get the selected items in regular way via selection model.

Comment: I deployed it in Android, and its hard to implement multiple selection. That's why I used checkboxes.

Comment: @UlukBiy, hi, how to do it? Can you give a clue? I mean, the binding stuff?

Comment: Hmm.. but before have you looked into CheckBoxListCell.forListView(...) ?

Comment: I guess CheckBoxListCell.forListView will not be applicable for this because I cant overide its appearance.

Comment: If you have a property field in a **Sector** class which can be bound to selected property of the checkbox, then it is easy to change the appearance of CheckBoxListCell by extending it.

Comment: I think the question is: does your `Sector` class has a `boolean` property which corresponds to the checkbox. Perhaps you can post the code for `Sector`?

Comment: Can you post me an example about a CheckBoxListCell that is bound to a boolean property, Please!

Comment: @EthylCasin search this site for CheckBoxListCell,or for "checkbox listview" and you will many examples. Don't forget to specify the javafx tag while searching.

Answer (score 1):

There is `isSelected()` method in JavaFX for the same.

Answer (score -2):

You could add a `CheckBox` field to `Sector` and assign it in the `updateItem` method:

```
sector.setCheckBox(checkbox);
```

You can then iterate through all the elements in your ListView:

```
sectorList.getItems().forEach((sector) -> {
    boolean selected = sector.getCheckBox().isSelected();
    // do whatever needs to be done
})
```

**Update**

You could also add a `BooleanProperty` to `Sector` and bind it to the selectedProperty of the CheckBox like this:

```
checkbox.selectedProperty().bind(selector.yourBooleanProperty);
```

And the check this property in the foreach loop

Comment: no: never-ever mix view-aspects (here that would be the checkBox) into the data (= Sector)